# writing to a file , subprocess. call output returns nothing

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I have a small code which tracks down cpu use periodically. Somehow when I try to create a file ( "wb" or "w" mode) the file is created but its empty. Any idea why is it so?

W/O the file handler:

```
import subprocess
import os

MESSAGE = "mpstat -P ALL | awk '{print $4}'"
SLEEP = "sleep 1"

cmds = [MESSAGE, SLEEP]


def runCommands(commands = cmds):
    count =0
    while True:
            for cmd in cmds:
                    count+=1
                    subprocess.call(cmd, shell = True)


runCommands()
```

With file handler:

```
import subprocess
import os

MESSAGE = "mpstat -P ALL | awk '{print $4}'"
SLEEP = "sleep 1"

cmds = [MESSAGE, SLEEP]


def runCommands(commands = cmds):
    count =0
    while True:
         for cmd in cmds:
            count+=1
            with open('cpu_usage.txt', 'w')as f:
                subprocess.call(cmd, stdout = f, shell = True)


runCommands()
```

mpstat gives a standard output ( not a standard error ). The objective is to gather cpu and memory usage every second using python and embed in an application to gather the data and graphically output the same. I know that psutil is a good framework in this regard but if you didnt play with it much. It could also solve my issue given the fact that in the end i have a graphical output which contains mem and cpu use per sec.

Eventually I am looking for an output which is of the form:

```
      %CPU   %MEM 

      ..      ..
      ..      ..
      ..      ..
```

and in the end a time vs CPU and time vs memory will suffice the need. I am just one step into this problem by grabbing the cpu value. `ps aux` doesnt seem to be a good command to do what I need , although it gives the output similar to the one I want. Any ideas/thoughts/suggestions.

Comment: fix your indentation :P

Comment: why dont u use subprocess.popen() from which u can std out and std err too

Comment: I don't need stderr as mpstat is gives me standard out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're opening a file with the 'w' argument, it is *created* anew every time, meaning that when your `while` loop finished (it wouldn't in your example, but let's assume it does) - the last thing executed with the file is the `sleep 1` command which doesn't print anything. Open the file with the 'a' (append) flag and you'll have all the `mpstat` outputs in it.

See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files for full reference.

But in general, try to do more processing in Python and rely less on OS commands, like below (though I'd still not do the AWK stuff at all, but anyway).

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

CPU = "mpstat -P ALL | awk 'NR==4 { print $3 }'"
MEM = "free -m | awk 'NR==3 { print $4 }'"

def runCommands():
    count = 0
    f = open('cpu_usage.txt', 'a')
    while True:
         t = str(int(time.time()))
         cpu = subprocess.check_output(CPU, shell = True).strip()
         mem = subprocess.check_output(MEM, shell = True).strip()

         f.write(' '.join([t, cpu, mem]))
         f.write('\n')
         f.flush()

         time.sleep(1)

runCommands()
```

Comment: Nice. That eventually gives me the file with respective contents. ANy suggestion to how to get both memory and cpu usage stats written on the same file? I was thinking of using `psutil.virtual_memory()` but the overhead f creating a new file, parsing and plotting will be too much.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part of the question. Could you maybe specify in the original question what format you want the output file to look like in the end - might help with answering. Cheers

Comment: Hi martin, I updated the original question. Let me know if you have any thoughts on it.

Comment: Updated the answer - you can fiddle around with the basics, but that's a general mockup that works.

Comment: Get the following errors:

`./cpu_mpstat3.py: line 5: CPU: command not found
./cpu_mpstat3.py: line 6: MEM: command not found
./cpu_mpstat3.py: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./cpu_mpstat3.py: line 8: `def runCommands():'
`

Comment: Works perfectly for me, maybe you're using Python 3 or something? Just plug the two os commands where CPU and MEM are in the code and you should be fine. Again, this works well for mein Python 2.7.